# Poco HTMLForm multiple parameter with same key

Tags: c++, forms, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco::Net:HTMLForm to POST a request.

Now I want to put in the form:

```
form[key] = value1
form[key] = value2
```

And the server side can transform key to a list [value1, value2].
I can do this while test with Postman, but in POCO HTMLForm, value2 will overwrite value1.

Is there any way to implement this in Poco::Net::HTMLForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
form.add(name, value);
```

to add multiple fields with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

<s>No, as you noticed - same keys will be [overwritten](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.6.1/Net/src/NameValueCollection.cpp#L71-L78). Assembling data yourself is not that complicated, though:</s>

```
?key=value1&key=value2
```

Issue [filed](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1056) on github.

UPDATE: use `form.add(name, value)`, it will allow multiple values.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is in my case the URL may becomes too long and would be discarded by some service.

Comment: That's a matter of GET or POST; there's no magic in Poco HTMLForm, eventually your parameters will become string, either in URL (GET) or in the request body (POST).

Comment: You should accept the answer below, I was mistaken.